# How do I get my websites FB 'like' button to post a link to my website on visiters FB wall/news feed

Tags: web, facebook-like

My website has a FB like button.  When a visitor to my site clicks this facebook 'like' button it doesn't place a link to my website on their FB profile or feed.  I've looked through many of these q&a's and googled etc. I'm a novice but have spent a lot of time trying to find the solution what am I missing?  I got this code from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.wix.com/coastalinclusion/playground" data-             send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st, good job on having your og tags listed correctly on http://www.wix.com/coastalinclusion/playground, as most don't.

However, where you're placing the like button is not allowing the facebook dialog to appear properly so the liker can post the link to their wall.

Your facebook plugin is (with a user defined width of 450):

```
element.style {
  border: none;
  border-image: initial;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 225px;
  width: 401px;
}
```

however, the iframe you have it in is cropping the facebook dialog

```
element.style {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  left: 1404px;
  top: 112px;
  width: 96px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

hence it getting cropped out.